# Optimizing an array mapping operation in python

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, vectorization

I am trying to get rid of an inefficient set of nested for loops in python.  I have an array that I will call S(f<sub>k</sub>,f<sub>q</sub>) that needs to be mapped onto a different array that I will call Z(f<sub>i</sub>,α<sub>j</sub>).  The arguments are all sampling frequencies.  Both arrays have the same dimensions, which are user-selected.  The mapping rule is fairly straightforward:

f<sub>i</sub> = 0.5 · (f<sub>k</sub> - f<sub>q</sub>) 
α<sub>j</sub> = f<sub>k</sub> + f<sub>q</sub>

Currently I'm performing this via a series of nested for loops:

```
import numpy as np
nrows = 64
ncolumns = 16384
fk = np.fft.fftfreq(nrows)
fq = np.fft.fftfreq(ncolumns)
# using random numbers here to simplify the example
# in practice S is the result of several FFTs and complex multiplications
S = np.random.random(size=(nrows,ncolumns)) + 1j*np.random.random(size=(nrows,ncolumns))

fi = []
alphaj = []
Z = []
for k in range(-nrows//2,nrows//2):
    for q in range(-ncolumns//2,ncolumns//2):
        fi.append(0.5*(fk[k] - fq[q]))
        alphaj.append(fk[k] + fq[q])
        Z.append(S[k,q])
```

Obviously this is highly inefficient -- with this approach the mapping operation takes longer than the actual calculation of S (which in practice is the result of several FFT's and complex multiplications).  I would like to find a way to vectorize this, but I'm having trouble coming up with the right approach.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Note: This is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61106912/data-structure-for-a-diamond-shaped-array-in-python) about how to store the results.  Since this is about optimization I thought it would be better to create two separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn’t use the negative indexing of your original function but by returning arrays you can use normal indexing to map values

```
def weirdMath():
    nrows = 64
    ncolumns = 16384
    fk = np.fft.fftfreq(nrows)
    fq = np.fft.fftfreq(ncolumns)
    S = np.random.random(size=(nrows,ncolumns)) + 1j*np.random.random(size=(nrows,ncolumns))

    fi = .5*fk[:,np.newaxis] - fq
    alphaj = fk[:,np.newaxis] + fq
    return fi, alphaj, S


>>> f1,a1=weirdMath()
>>> f1.size
1048576
>>> f1[32,:10]
array([ 0.25      ,  0.24993896,  0.24987793,  0.24981689,  0.24975586,
        0.24969482,  0.24963379,  0.24957275,  0.24951172,  0.24945068])
```

Proof with rolling of axes added to match order of output in original code. Note: S was modified to np.arange() so that value comparison between functions could be directly matched:

```
def origCode():
    nrows = 64
    ncolumns = 16384
    fk = np.fft.fftfreq(nrows)
    fq = np.fft.fftfreq(ncolumns)
# using random numbers here to simplify the example
# in practice S is the result of several FFTs and complex multiplications
    #S = np.random.random(size=(nrows,ncolumns)) + 1j*np.random.random(size=(nrows,ncolumns))
    S = np.arange(nrows*ncolumns).reshape(nrows, ncolumns)
    fi = []
    alphaj = []
    Z = []

    for k in range(-nrows//2,nrows//2):
        for q in range(-ncolumns//2,ncolumns//2):
            fi.append(0.5*fk[k] - fq[q])
            alphaj.append(fk[k] + fq[q])
            Z.append(S[k,q])
    return fi, alphaj,Z 


def weirdMathWithRoll():
    nrows = 64
    ncolumns = 16384
    rowRollAdj = nrows%2
    colRollAdj = ncolumns%2

    fk = np.roll(np.fft.fftfreq(nrows), shift=(-nrows//2) + rowRollAdj, axis=0)

    fq = np.roll(np.fft.fftfreq(ncolumns), (-ncolumns//2) + colRollAdj)
    S = np.random.random(size=(nrows,ncolumns)) + 1j*np.random.random(size=(nrows,ncolumns))
    S = np.arange(nrows*ncolumns).reshape(nrows, ncolumns)
    s2 = np.roll(S,ncolumns//2 + colRollAdj, axis=1)
    s3 = np.roll(s2,nrows//2 + rowRollAdj, axis=0)

    fi = .5*fk[:,np.newaxis] - fq
    alphaj = fk[:,np.newaxis] + fq

    return fi, alphaj, s3

def testMath():
    f,a,z = origCode()
    f1,a1,s1 = weirdMathWithRoll()

    fMatch = f==f1.flatten()
    aMatch = a==a1.flatten()
    sMatch = z==s1.flatten()
    return (np.all(fMatch), np.all(aMatch), np.all(sMatch))
```

Output of proof:

```
>>> testMath()
(True, True, True)
```

Performance improvement:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(origCode, number = 1)
0.984715332997439
>>> timeit.timeit(weirdMathWithRoll, number = 1)
0.051891374998376705
```

Comment: I there is a typo in your function around line 6 but if I change that to fi = 0.5*(fk[:,np.newaxis[ - fq) then I get a very reasonable result.  The exact ordering of the arrays is different than in my example, but I think that is a detail of how the original fk and fq are ordered by numpy.fft.fftfreq.  Do you have any suggestions for how to map S to Z?  Put differently, how would I map the indices (k,q) to (i,j)? If that works then I think this would basically solve my optimization problem.

Comment: @RyanLynch apologies for the error on line 6, it has been corrected. I may be misunderstanding, but Z is for for index referencing? fi, alphaj and S all have the the same shape, (64, 16384), so I think you don’t need Z, just reference all 3 arrays with the same indexes

Comment: just as a particular k and q index of fk and fq map to some value of fi and alphaj, so to does some particular pair of k an q for S map to a particular i and j for Z.  I'm not sure, from your method, how to perform that map.

Comment: @RyanLynch maybe if you could post a small sample of actual data for S and how it corresponds to fi and alphaj. From what I am seeing k and q simply iterate over indexes for fk and fj. So fk[0] and fj[0] correspond to S[0,0] which is appended to Z. With my method fi[0,0] would correspond with alphaj[0,0] and with S[0,0]. I may be missing something, I’m sure the math behind this is over my head, but from what I can see in your code my logic should be sound.

Comment: @RyanLynch I have added a proof to my method showing that Z is not needed, simply returning S with axes rotated (and flattened if a 1D array or list is required) produces the same results with a 20x performance improvement.

Comment: I didn't immediately appreciate that fi[0,0] and alphaj[0,0] map to S[0,0] with this approach.  I have to change some downstream processing, but started this and I can reproduce my original results! I also get a factor of **11x** speedup over the approach I show in my question (along with storing the results in a defaultdict as shown in the related question I link to), and a factor of **40x** speedup over my every first approach of concatenating arrays (instead of appending lists) and using a regular dict (and checking for the first occurrence of certain keys).  Awesome!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does indexing with negative k values do what you want? In Python/numpy fk[-1] means last, fk[-2] means second to the last, etc.

```
In [90]: S = np.arange(1,11)                                                                           
In [91]: Z = []                                                                                        
In [92]: for k in range(-5,5): 
    ...:     Z.append(S[k]) 
    ...:                                                                                               

In [94]: S                                                                                             
Out[94]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
In [95]: Z                                                                                             
Out[95]: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Or with slicing:

```
In [96]: np.concatenate([S[5:],S[:5]])                                                                 
Out[96]: array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5])
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps with the mapping of the two arrays.  I am already using negative indexing with this particular implementation when I loop through the arrays (though one doesn't have to index in that way).  The deeper issue is how to map the 2D arrays as shown above.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure you understood what that negative range indexing was doing.  It doesn't seem very logical or useful to me.