# Data structure for a diamond-shaped array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-structures

I have two arrays that are related to each other via a mapping operation.  I will call them  S(f<sub>k</sub>,f<sub>q</sub>) and Z(f<sub>i</sub>,α<sub>j</sub>).  The arguments are all sampling frequencies.  The mapping rule is fairly straightforward:

f<sub>i</sub> = 0.5 · (f<sub>k</sub> - f<sub>q</sub>) 
α<sub>j</sub> = f<sub>k</sub> + f<sub>q</sub>

S is the result of several FFTs and complex multiplications and is defined on a rectangular grid.  However, Z is defined on a diamond-shaped grid and it is not clear to me how best to store this.  The image below is an attempt at visualizing the operation for a simple example of a 4×4 array, but in general the dimensions are not equal and are much larger (maybe 64×16384, but this is user-selectable).  Blue points are the resulting values of f<sub>i</sub> and α<sub>j</sub> and the text describes how these are related to f<sub>k</sub>, f<sub>q</sub>, and the discrete indices.
[image: Diamond-shaped array representation]
The diamond-shaped nature of Z means that in one "row" there will be "columns" that fall in between the "columns" of adjacent "rows".  Another way to think of this is that f<sub>i</sub> can take on fractional index values!

Note that using zero's or nan's to fill in elements that don't exist in any given row has two drawbacks 1) it inflates the size of what may already be a very large 2-D array and 2) it does not really represent the true nature of Z (e.g. the array size will not really be correct).

Currently I am using a dictionary indexed on the actual values of α<sub>j</sub> to store the results:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
nrows = 64
ncolumns = 16384
fk = np.fft.fftfreq(nrows)
fq = np.fft.fftfreq(ncolumns)
# using random numbers here to simplify the example
# in practice S is the result of several FFTs and complex multiplications
S = np.random.random(size=(nrows,ncolumns)) + 1j*np.random.random(size=(nrows,ncolumns))

ret = defaultdict(lambda: {"fi":[],"Z":[]})
for k in range(-nrows//2,nrows//2):
    for q in range(-ncolumns//2,ncolumns//2):
        fi = 0.5*fk[k] - fq[q]
        alphaj = fk[k] + fq[q]
        Z = S[k,q]
        ret[alphaj]["fi"].append(fi)
        ret[alphaj]["Z"].append(Z)
```

I still find this a bit cumbersome to work with and wonder if anyone has suggestions for a better approach?  "Better" here would be defined as more computationally and memory efficient and/or easier to interact with and visualize using something like matplotlib.

Note: This is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61104413/optimizing-an-array-mapping-operation-in-python) about how to get rid of those nasty for-loops.  Since this is about storing the results I thought it would be better to create two separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the [answer to a related question on optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61104413/optimizing-an-array-mapping-operation-in-python) effectively solved my problem of how to better store the data.  The new code returns 2-D arrays for f<sub>i</sub>, %alpha;<sub>j</sub>, and these can be used to directly index S.  So to get all values of S for %alpha;<sub>j</sub> = 0, for example, one can do

```
S[alphaj == 0]
```

I can use this pretty effectively and it seems like the quickest way to create a reasonable data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can still view it as a straight two-dimensional array. But you can *represent* it as an array of rows, each row of which has a different number of items. For example, here's your 4x4 as a 2D array: (each `0` here is a unique data item)

```
xxx0xxx
xx0x0xx
x0x0x0x
0x0x0x0
x0x0x0x
xx0x0xx
xxx0xxx
```

Its sparse representation would be:

```
[
  [0],
  [0,0],
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0,0,0],
  [0,0,0],
  [0,0],
  [0]
]
```

With this representation you eliminate the empty space. There's a little math involved in converting from Color Temperature to row, and from Spectral Frequency to column (and vice-versa), but that's tractable. You know the bounds and that items are evenly spaced out across each row. So it should be easy enough to do the translation.

Unless I'm missing something . . .

Comment: would this then be implemented as a list of lists?  I think that is similar to what I am doing now, which is to have "rows" be dictionary entries with items that represent values of fi and Z.

Comment: @RyanLynch I suppose it is similar to your dictionary. I think an array of rows, if you can do it (I'm not a Python programmer), would be faster and take a bit less memory. And I would suggest a structure or object rather than having parallel rows for `fi` and `z`. As for viewing with matplotlib or something similar, I just don't know.